# Url Rewriting with hidden rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently facing a problem with one url rewriting rule. 
[I'm running on Apache 2.4.23]

I'm trying to make a redirection for certain pages. Here are my rules :

```
RewriteRule ^clubs[^/]?$  club.php?job=display [L,NC]<br />
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]*)$   club.php?job=detail&name=$1 [L]<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !club\.php                                      [NC]<br />
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]+)/?(.+)?/?       club.php?job=detail&name=$1&action=$2           [NC,L]
```

The problem is that rule for "clubs" is working well. But those for club aren't working.
If I go to the url http://mysite/club , I can see that it has already been rewrited to http://mysite/club.php?
And if I go to the url http://mysite/club/clubName , I can see that it has already been rewrited to http://mysite/club.php/clubName?
And all of this because the file club.php exists. If I had redirected 'club' to 'anythingElseButNonExistingFile' , it would have worked.
Even if I remove all the lines in my .htaccess file, this happens. So I suppose there's another .htaccess file with other rules somewhere I do not have access to.

So I changed my rules for 'club' to :

```
RewriteRule ^club.php/(.+)                     club.php?job=detail&name=$1 [L]<br />
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}                  !club\.php                                     [NC]<br />
RewriteRule ^club/([^/]+)/?(.+)?/?        club.php?job=detail&name=$1&action=$2          [NC,L]<br />
```

So now, if I try to go to :
http://mysite/club/clubName, it works, it redirects to 
http://mysite/club.php/clubName?job=detail&name=clubName
Not nice but working...

But if I try to go to http://mySite/club/clubName/addPhoto, url is not properly rewritten. I get :
http://club.php/clubName/addPhoto?job=detail&name=clubName%2FaddPhoto
I don't know how to get rid of this...

I hope this is not too much confused and that someone will have a solution... Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But those for club aren't working. If I go to the url http://mysite/club , I can see that it has already been rewrited to http://mysite/club.php?

You need to disable [content negociation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html) by `Options -MultiViews` in your .htaccess.

> And if I go to the url http://mysite/club/clubName , I can see that it has already been rewrited to http://mysite/club.php/clubName?

This is the fault of the combination of content negociation and *PathInfo* feature (see [AcceptPathInfo directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)). The *PathInfo* feature allows an extra (and unexistant) path behind the file (/clubName in your example) while the content negociation internally rewrite club into club.php.

So to not be bothered when doing rewriting, it might be a good idea to eliminate both with these statements (in your .htaccess file):

```
Options -MultiViews
AcceptPathInfo off
```

Comment: Ok, this works perfectly and has solved my problem ! Thank you very much for the explications and the documentation links that were useful too and added to my bookmarks ;-)